# Looking for online Judge Engine that support Python

Tags: python

I am writing a website which intends to be a place for use to paste/answer coding questions. Especially Python.

So, I am looking for an "online judge" engine that could support Python(c/c++/java/# could be a plus), so that the guy who paste the question could provide a simple test, then others could answer it with the onlinejudge to verify it works or not.

Is that a known good Online Judge I could use?

I do find several [here](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:onlinejudge), but not match what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ideone API](http://ideone.com/api/) - free for non commercial apps.

Answer (score 4):

The [Sphere Online Judge](http://www.spoj.pl/) supports Python.

The questions from the old [Google Codejam](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest), along with the problems at [Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net) are both language independent, and are helpful for practicing in any language.

Comment: I'll second: SPOJ and Euler are two of the best online judges out there.

Comment: These 2 sites are really good - I can't find a good way that I could use on my site though. SPOG seems has the service, if been paid for.

I am just looking for a small one that could support python to use on my site - which are focus on a set of IT/algorithm related questions, I wish the solution posted on the site could be verified

Comment: You can try with Ideone API (for Q&A you do not need the full OJ facility).